# How to change a file based in a second file

Tags: unix, awk

I would like to convert a file that have the letters `A T C G` in `A B`.
For this I have two files (file1 and file2).

The first 2 rows and 10 columns of file1 (the one that I need to convert) are:
`G G G G A A C C A G 
G A G A A A C C G G`

head of file2 (columns 1,2 and 4 are not useful here):
`10000135098 A G 1
10000267940 A G 2
10000305793 A G 3
10000393248 A C 4
10000434180 A G 5
10000471078 A G 6
10000516404 A G 7
10000533815 A G 8
10000571340 A G 9
10000845494 A G 10`

I tried to do:
`awk 'BEGIN {FS=" ";OFS=" "} {$1=$1; print}' file1 | awk 'BEGIN {FS="";OFS=""} NR==FNR {for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) {a[$3]="A";next} {if($i in a) print a[$3]; else print "B"}}' file2 -`

But nothing happens.

The desirable output would be:
`A A A B B B B B B A
 A B A B B B B B A A`

Any suggestion?

Comment: From the AWK code, I have no idea what you are trying to achieve. Would you mind expanding on the core idea here. Maybe add some indentation to the code example as well.

Comment: `awk 'BEGIN {FS=" ";OFS=" "} {$1=$1; print}' file1` just squeezes all white space to singe blank chars and then `awk 'BEGIN {FS=""` is undefined behavior per POSIX but on some awks (e.g. gawk) will split each line into one character per field. All of that seems extremely unlikely to be what you want but then you haven't told us what you DO want so idk...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have no idea what you are trying to achieve and your code makes no sense to me but this awk with given inputs seems to produce correct output:

```
$ awk '
NR==FNR {                     # hash $3 of file2 use FNR as key
    a[FNR]=$3
    next
}
{
    for(i=1;i<=NF;i++)        # for each char in file1
        $i=($i==a[i]?"A":"B") # replace with A or B depending on
}1' file2 file1
A A A B B B B B B A
A B A B B B B B A A
```

Comment: Thank you @James.   
I am a beginner so sometimes I  have difficult to write the codes.   
It looks like worked very well.   
Thanks again